# Running TCP echo server example: Uncaught ConnectionReset

Tags: deno

I'm trying to run the TCP echo server example with

```
deno run --allow-net https://deno.land/std/examples/echo_server.ts
```

I get this output:

```
deno run --allow-net https://deno.land/std/examples/echo_server.ts
Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
error: Uncaught ConnectionReset: Connection reset by peer (os error 54)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_minimal.ts:63:11)
    at Object.sendAsyncMinimal ($deno$/ops/dispatch_minimal.ts:106:10)
    at async Object.read ($deno$/ops/io.ts:39:17)
    at async Object.copy ($deno$/io.ts:64:20)
```

deno 1.0.5
v8 8.4.300
typescript 3.9.2

Comment: do you have another service running on port `8080`?

Comment: Ugh, I seem to have a stuck process occupying the port.

Answer (score 2):

It was a matter of a process getting stuck and occupying the port.